# SSL certificate expiration date in Application gateway

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-application-gateway

We have an Azure Application gateway with SSL certificates. We know that our certificate expires soon and we need to renew it. Our problem is that we can not get the actual expiration date in the gateway information, at least from the portal.

Does somebody know where we can retrieve this info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may not be a quick way to do this from Azure portal directly.

Look at this blog from Feb, 2018 about a PowerShell module created to tackle exactly this kind of scenarios by [Azure Rapid Response](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/response/) team.

[Use AzureRMAppGWCert to list certificate details of Azure App Gateway](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netgeeks/2018/02/22/use-azurermappgwcert-to-list-certificate-details-of-azure-app-gateway/)

[image]

This Module is Published at https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRMAppGWCert

In order to install just open the powershell as Administrator and type:

```
Install-Module AzureRMAppGWCert
Import-Module AzureRMAppGWCert
```

**Example**: Listing all digital certificates associated with a single Application Gateway:

This Module will list all certificates associated with Application Gateway and generate an output like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureRMAppGWCert -RG OfficeClient -AppGWName AppGateway

 AppGWName : AppGateway
 ListnerName : appGatewayHttpListener
 Subject : CN=*.hepoca.com, O=Hepoca Armarios e Servicos Ltda - EPP, L=Taguatinga, S=Distrito Federal, C=BR
 Issuer : CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
 SerialNumber : 0E99D5E2EBBE329CFE2DDE29C1D7D343
 Thumbprint : 5FD6F2A7BC4BD095198AE55D1A0A76D46365C6B9
 NotBefore : 3/13/2017 7:00:00 PM
 NotAfter : 5/2/2018 7:00:00 AM

 AppGWName : AppGateway
 ListnerName : HTTPs8080
 Subject : CN=*.hepoca.com, O=Hepoca Armarios e Servicos Ltda - EPP, L=Taguatinga, S=Distrito Federal, C=BR
 Issuer : CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
 SerialNumber : 0E99D5E2EBBE329CFE2DDE29C1D7D343
 Thumbprint : 5FD6F2A7BC4BD095198AE55D1A0A76D46365C6B9
 NotBefore : 3/13/2017 7:00:00 PM
 NotAfter : 5/2/2018 7:00:00 AM

 AppGWName : AppGateway
 HTTPSetting : appGatewayBackendHttpSettings
 RuleName : rule1
 BackendCertName : webjson-pub
 Subject : E=a@a.com, CN=webjson.arr.local, OU=Arr, O=ARR, L=Irving, S=TX, C=US
 Issuer : E=a@a.com, CN=webjson.arr.local, OU=Arr, O=ARR, L=Irving, S=TX, C=US
 SerialNumber : 00B1722AB4D0FB8CAA
 Thumbprint : 573C70769A40CF4D01769926A212009598462436
 NotBefore : 11/28/2017 12:45:23 PM
 NotAfter : 11/28/2018 12:45:23 PM
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Useful for those using the `Az.*` modules: https://github.com/Welasco/AzureRMAppGWCert/blob/master/AzAppGWCert.psm1